# Unresolved attribute reference 'astype' for class 'bool'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, integer, boolean, compiler-warnings

I moved from Jupyter lab to Spyder and have a program that *seems* to work fine.

Problem is its taking ages to write and Im getting lost in all the modifications, so I moved to GitHub, which obliges me to work in PyCharm.

PyCharm is pretty good, although it seems to lack (or I havent found) some variable and file explorer functions Ive (as a newbie) found helpful in Spyder. I have absolutely no idea about GitHub or PyCharm and am learning as I go.

PyCharm seems to find an awful lot of "mistakes" in my code that I gradually work through to eliminate.

This time, as soon as I pasted new code from Spyder into Pycharm, its giving me this warning under "astype":

*Unresolved attribute reference 'astype' for class 'bool'*

Heres the offending code:

```
# Populate df2 based on conditions
for col in df.columns:
    df2[('ATH', col)] = (df[col] >= df[col].expanding().max()).astype(int)
    df2[('ATL', col)] = -(df[col] <= df[col].expanding().min()).astype(int)
    df2[('12MH', col)] = (df[col] >= rolling_12m_high[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('12ML', col)] = -(df[col] <= rolling_12m_low[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('3MH', col)] = (df[col] >= rolling_3m_high[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('3ML', col)] = -(df[col] <= rolling_3m_low[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('1MH', col)] = (df[col] >= rolling_1m_high[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('1ML', col)] = -(df[col] <= rolling_1m_low[col]).astype(int)
```

Im still a newbie, but can usually manage to debug simple stuff with the help of ChatGPT, but in this case its suggesting to substitute my own code with my own code to resolve the unresolved attribute! Sometimes it can be pretty unhelpful!

Ive pasted the whole function below in case it helps.

Basically, all its doing is checking the columns of a dataframe of daily closing prices for a bunch of stocks and creating columns in a new dataframe of 1s and 0s for: all time high and low of the column, 12 month high and low, 3 month high and low and 1 month.

PyCharm doesnt seem to like the fact Im changing booleans to integers. It might not even be a problem, but since Im new and Pycharms flagged it I thought Id ask.

Thanks for any help!

```
def highs_and_lows(df, t):
global total_stocks
global yahoo_idx_code
global close_idx
global lookback

# Calculate rolling max and min for 3 months and 1 month
rolling_12m_high = df.rolling(window=t[0]).max()
rolling_12m_low = df.rolling(window=t[0]).min()
rolling_3m_high = df.rolling(window=t[1]).max()
rolling_3m_low = df.rolling(window=t[1]).min()
rolling_1m_high = df.rolling(window=t[2]).max()
rolling_1m_low = df.rolling(window=t[2]).min()

# Initialize df2 with 0 values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['ATH', 'ATL', '12MH', '12ML', '3MH', '3ML', '1MH', '1ML'], df.columns]))

# Populate df2 based on conditions
for col in df.columns:
    df2[('ATH', col)] = (df[col] >= df[col].expanding().max()).astype(int)
    df2[('ATL', col)] = -(df[col] <= df[col].expanding().min()).astype(int)
    df2[('12MH', col)] = (df[col] >= rolling_12m_high[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('12ML', col)] = -(df[col] <= rolling_12m_low[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('3MH', col)] = (df[col] >= rolling_3m_high[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('3ML', col)] = -(df[col] <= rolling_3m_low[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('1MH', col)] = (df[col] >= rolling_1m_high[col]).astype(int)
    df2[('1ML', col)] = -(df[col] <= rolling_1m_low[col]).astype(int)

# Display the resulting DataFrame df2
# print(df2)

# Group by level 0 and sum within each group
df2_sum = df2.T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().T

# Display the resulting DataFrame df2_sum
# print(df2_sum)

#############################################################################
# PLOTTING
#############################################################################

p1 = df2_sum.tail(lookback)
pidx = close_idx.tail(lookback)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))

# Define colors for each level 0 label
colors = {
    'ATH': 'deepskyblue',
    'ATL': 'saddlebrown',
    '12MH': 'forestgreen',
    '12ML': 'red',
    '3MH': 'mediumseagreen',
    '3ML': 'tomato',
    '1MH': 'palegreen',
    '1ML': 'peachpuff'
}

for label in reversed(p1.columns):
    plt.bar(p1.index, p1[label], label=label, color=colors[label])

# ax.plot(p1.index, p1, linewidth=1)  # Use the 'legend' parameter
ax.set_ylabel('Highs and Lows')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
# Add title and legend
plt.title('Highs and Lows')
plt.legend(labels=p1.columns, loc='upper left')  # Use column names for legend labels

# Add a horizontal dotted line to show where fundos might be
ax.axhline(y=0, color='black', linestyle='--')

# Add index to other axis
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.plot(p1.index, pidx, 'black', label=yahoo_idx_code, linewidth=2)
ax3.set_ylabel(yahoo_idx_code, color='black')

lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax3.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='upper left')

plt.show()

return df2_sum
```